# c# math formula output inconsistency

Tags: c#

here is my formula:

```
y = b*exp(-((x-c)^2)/2(d^2)) if x < c, else y = b*exp(-(x-c)^2/2g^2);
```

this is how i coded it:

```
        for (double x = 0; x <= 7D; x += .01D)
        {
            b = 6.0410638; c = 2.1344769; d = 0.59183047; g = 0.77384504;
            if (x < c)
                y = b * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow((x - c), 2)) / (2 * Math.Pow(d, 2D));
            else
                y = b * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow((x - c), 2)) / (2 * Math.Pow(g, 2D));
            qResults.Rows.Add(x, y);
        }
```

the output:

```
    0.0529826172
0.05528786
0.05768187
0.0601675063
0.0627477
0.06542546
0.06820385
0.07108601
0.074075155
0.0771745443
0.08038754
0.08371756
0.08716809
0.0907426849
0.0944449753
0.0982786641
0.102247514
0.106355369
0.110606134
0.115003787
0.119552381
0.124256022
0.1291189
0.13414526
0.139339417
0.144705743
0.150248691
0.155972764
0.16188252
0.167982608
0.1742777
0.180772528
0.187471911
0.1943807
0.201503783
0.2088461
0.2164127
0.224208578
0.232238829
0.2405086
0.24902302
0.257787317
0.2668067
```

is there a problem with my syntax?

the output should be:

```
0.009332048
0.009915393
0.010532198
0.011184179
0.011873133
0.012600931
0.013369526
0.014180954
0.015037339
0.015940891
0.016893914
0.017898806
0.01895806
0.020074273
0.021250142
0.022488471
0.023792173
0.025164271
0.026607905
0.028126332
0.029722928
0.031401194
0.033164757
0.035017372
0.036962928
0.039005447
0.041149089
0.043398156
0.045757092
0.048230485
0.050823073
0.053539744
0.05638554
0.059365657
0.062485449
0.065750429
0.069166271
0.072738815
0.076474061
0.08037818
0.084457508
0.088718551
0.093167983
0.097812651
0.102659571
0.107715931
0.112989091
0.118486582
0.124216105
0.130185532
0.136402905
0.142876432
0.149614489
0.156625615
0.163918513
0.171502045
0.17938523
0.187577239
0.196087395
0.204925165
0.21410016
0.223622125
0.233500937
0.2437466
0.254369235
0.265379079
0.276786473
0.288601856
0.30083576
0.313498797
0.326601652
0.340155077
0.354169874
0.368656891
0.383627009
0.39909113
0.415060167
0.431545027
0.448556606
0.466105768
0.484203337
0.502860078
0.522086688
0.541893773
0.562291841
0.583291279
0.604902341
0.627135126
0.649999569
0.673505413
0.697662199
0.722479244
0.747965622
0.774130146
0.800981347
0.828527458
0.856776387
0.885735705
0.915412619
0.945813957
0.976946142
1.008815173
1.041426608
1.074785537
1.108896564
1.143763787
1.179390775
1.21578055
```

Comment: So, what is it supposed to be?????

Comment: Are you comparing the output against something with higher precision?

Comment: We don't know what values are being printed

Comment: @Doc he's not asking whether there is a syntax _error_, he's asking about (syntax) problem. You know, like a goof-up

Comment: where did you get the "expected result"? Did you try to calculate yourself that these results are precise?

Comment: Never try converting a math equation in a loop, you're asking for trouble. Do a static variable, just 1 value. If it doesn't work once, it won't work 700 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your formula, the code should be:

```
    for (double x = 0; x <= 7D; x += .01D)
    {
        b = 6.0410638; c = 2.1344769; d = 0.59183047; g = 0.77384504;
        if (x < c)
            y = b * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x - c, 2) / (2 * Math.Pow(d, 2D)));
        else
            y = b * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x - c, 2) / (2 * Math.Pow(g, 2D)));
        qResults.Rows.Add(x, y);
    }
```

Basically, the `Math.Exp` function should be applied to the result of the division, not just to the result of `-Math.Pow(x - c, 2)`

Also, it's not very clear based on the formula and your code example whether you need to divide by 2  in the exponent computation, then multiply the result by d^2, or actually divide by 2 * d^2 as you are doing in the implementation.

Comment: I'm glad you added that clarification, because I was scrolling up and down looking for the difference!